# Thomae function - line patterns

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, graphing-functions

This question is related to [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2626385/thomae-function-points-lying-on-the-same-line).

I'm tutoring some first year university students calculus, and next week, discussing continuity, I plan to talk about Thomae function:

$$ f(x) = \begin{cases} 
      \frac{1}{q} & \text{ if } x\in \mathbb{Q},\ x = \frac{p}{q},\ p \in \mathbb{Z},\ q \in \mathbb{N},\ \gcd(p, q) = 1    \\
      0 &  \text{ if } x\not\in \mathbb{Q} \text{ or } x=0
   \end{cases} $$

Proving that the function is continuous at each irrational point, I wanted to give them some intuition about it before going into the proof. I was plotting some graph, including the one below where

- the red point is $(\sqrt{\pi},0)$
- the blue points are $\left(\frac{p}{q},\frac{1}{q}\right)$ for $q=10,11,\ldots,200$ (I removed the first ten point to have a nicer plot), so there are the point $\left(\frac{[q*\sqrt{\pi}]}{q},\frac{1}{q}\right)$, where $\left[ \cdot \right]$ is the *round* function.

My goal was to exhibit that the closer $x$ get to the irrationnal number $\sqrt{\pi}$, the higher $q$ has to be.

But some line pattern are really clear in the plot,

[image]

This is valid for any irrational number, it's even better when taking $\pi$ as irrational limit. (in here the higher $q$ is the smaller the point is)
[image]

And with some zoom ($q=100,\ldots,1000$)
[image]

In the mentionned related question, Jack D'Aurizio gave a nice intuition for the existence of line in Thomas function, however, I wonder if anyone as some additionnal details. What do they converge to ? Intuitively I would have guess to $(0,\pi)$, but it does not look to be the case...

I'd like to understand the phenomena better, it is probably quite trivial with some property of rational, but I won't have much time before next week. So any input is welcome. Thanks

**Edit:** in the last plot I've added the first label of $q$ to understand how they behave. The pattern is expected, *going left* until the round function jumps, but still not sure how to explain the vertical lines.

Comment: In the 2nd part of your first displayed equation, you want $x$ **not** rational.

Comment: @GerryMyerson thanks for noting the typo, copy/paste error

Comment: If someone is interested I have solve my issue, as the lines between the points $p$ and $p+i$ will cross the axis at the approximation of the irrationnal number with $i$ as denominator. So using $\pi$ and looking at the most obvious/visual lines, they will cross at $x=22/7$, or for few of them at $21/7$ (when the round function offset everything by one). This works for any $i$, even if there are not as obvious there are many other lines, all 'converging' to $round(i * \pi)/i$.

Comment: I will post a complete proof/answer